# union of two var variables data type

Tags: c#

I have two var variable data type which I want to have a union of both. how can I do that?

```
var results = from table1 in dtTimeListTable.AsEnumerable()
              join table2 in readyDataTable.AsEnumerable() on (decimal)table1["Avnr"] equals (int)table2["Avnr"]
              orderby table2["Substation"],  table2["S6_NAME"]
              select new
              {
                   Substation = (string)table2["Substation"],
                   S6_NAME = (string)table2["S6_NAME"],
                   ptime = ((DateTime)table1["DBTM"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm").Substring(11, 5),
                   Wert = (decimal)table1["Wert"]
              };

var resultsMaxMin = from table1 in dtMaxMin.AsEnumerable()
              join table2 in readyDataTable.AsEnumerable() on (decimal)table1["Avnr"] equals (int)table2["Avnr"]
              orderby table2["Substation"], table2["S6_NAME"]
              select new
              {
                   Substation = (string)table2["Substation"],
                   S6_NAME = (string)table2["S6_NAME"],
                   ptime =table1["ptime"],
                   Wert = (decimal)table1["Wert"]
              };
```

Comment: You mean `var u = results.Union(resultsMaxMin);`?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: yes but if I do that I'll get an error

Comment: You should tell us about that in the question. Be specific. What error? Compile-time or run-time? What message?

Comment: perhaps it works with _dynamic_ instead of _var_

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'Union' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Union<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: It is Compile Error

Comment: Hmm, what if you say `var u = System.Linq.Enumerable.Union(results, resultsMaxMin);`? I cannot see what using directive you have to get Linq in scope. As far as I see you have said `.AsEnumerable()` everywhere, for some reason, and so I would think the extension method in `Enumerable` class should apply.

Comment: Wait, is `ptime` property of both anonymous type instantiations the same? Are you missing a cast to `string` or a `.ToString()` on the third code line from the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

This snippet may help:

```
            var list = new List<int>();

            var sublist1 = list.Select(x => new { foo = 1, bar = 2, baz = "baz" });
            var sublist2 = list.Select(x => new { bar = 3, foo = 1, baz = "baz" });
            var sublist3 = list.Select(x => new { foo = 3, bar = "a", baz = "baz" });
            var union1 = sublist1.Union(sublist2); // compilation error
            var union2 = sublist1.Union(sublist3); // compilation error
```

The Union() calls only work if the anonymous types match up exactly - *names*, *ordering* and *types* of fields. The errors in the snippet go away if you swap the order of `foo` and `bar` in the second select, and turn `bar` into an int value in the third.

In your example, `ptime` differs in type between the two lists - string and object.